# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) livewire.js:1 V3.3 on Xampp serer

Tags: laravel-livewire

I am trying to deploy a laravel livewire project using livewire version 3.3 but it is failing to load livewire. It is give the error Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) livewire.js:1   when I check developers.

It tried manually injecting livewire into my application but it wasn't being loaded.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Reference :
[Problem loading Livewire.js #242](https://github.com/livewire/livewire/issues/242#issuecomment-1862093389)

> The problem occurs because the configuration you provide is set up in such a way that when a request was made for /livewire/livewire.js, *Nginx* attempts to serve it as a static file and was checking if it existed on the filesystem.
>
> **But** it doesn’t! This file is served by Livewire. Nginx can’t find it, so it responds with a **404 error.**

So, right before the location block that sets your custom headers, add this one, which will prevent Nginx from interfering with this specific location:

```
location = /livewire/livewire.js {
    expires off;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}
```